# I am not able to insert values into my table having many to many relation?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have these three tables
loans,
customers,
loans_customers

loans has one record

```
insert into loans values(1234, "st", '2015-01-11', 2000);
```

customers has one record

```
insert into customers values(2276, "Anay", "Student");
```

I created another table loans_customers

```
create table loans_customers(
loans_customers_id decimal(10),
primary key(loans_customers_id),
loan_id decimal, 
customer_id decimal,
constraint FK_loans foreign key(loan_id) references loans(loan_id),
constraint FK_customers foreign key(customer_id) references customers(customer_id));
```

Now I'm trying to insert values

```
insert into loans_customers values(3376, ?, ?);
```

In the above syntax how to I give values in the place of **?,?** so that it should have many to many relationship perfectly.

Thank you,

Comment: Did you mean to use `INT` as a primary key? `DECIMAL` is intended for storing numbers with decimal components. `INT` is generally way more efficient to use.

Comment: I used Decimal as primary key.

Comment: Do you have any Primary Keys like `123.456`? or are thay all integers like 1, 2, 3, 2276

Comment: Yes, I see that, and it's almost always a mistake. `INT` is the type you need here.

Comment: @RiggsFolly They can't be stored in a `DECIMAL(10,0)` column anyway, there's no precision allowed.

Comment: @tadman I was just trying to make a point. I am in fact agreeing with you that the keys should be integers

Comment: How are the Primary Keys for `loans` and `customers` tables defined

Comment: let us think, they are int type, then what should be my query in the 
insert into loans_customers values(3376, ?, ?);

with what should i replace (3376, ?, ?)

Comment: Your Key fields should also be `INT Auto Increment` and then you dont need to specifiy them on an insert, as they get auto generated and are guaranteed to be unique in each table

Comment: Do a search for a simple mysql database design tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when using `insert`, you should always list the columns.  Then, you justinclude the ids:

```
insert into loans_customers(loans_customers_id, loan_id, customer_id)
    values(3376, 1234, 2276);
```

If you are using a prepared query with parameters, then you can supply the values using parameters.

Comment: I'm getting this.
0 17:35:55 insert into loans_customers(loans_customers_id, loan_id, customer_id) values(3376, 1234, 2376) Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`banking`.`loans_customers`, CONSTRAINT `FK_loans` FOREIGN KEY (`loan_id`) REFERENCES `loans` (`loan_id`))

Comment: @RamaKrishna . . . If those values exist in the reference tables (which is suggested by your example), then you should not be getting that error.